# Why does whereis() return undefined even though I just registered the process?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to start a simple process that will loop and receive addition or subtraction commands to calculate them. However when I register my process I try to print it with a `whereis()` to see if it is up and running and it returns `undefined`. Any idea what is going wrong?

```erlang
-module(math).
-export([start/0, math/0]).

start() -> register(myprocess, spawn(math, math(),  [])).
    
math() -> 
    io:format("~p~n", [whereis(myprocess)]),
    receive
        {add, X, Y} ->
            io:format("~p + ~p = ~p~n", [X,Y,X+Y]),
            math();
        {sub, X, Y} ->
            io:format("~p - ~p = ~p~n", [X,Y,X-Y]),
            math()
    end.
```

Here is my input in the erl shell as well:

```
Eshell V12.0  (abort with ^G)
1> c(math).      
{ok,math}
2> math:start().
undefined
```

Comment: it's a long time since I wrote any Erlang, but it looks to me like you're calling `math()` *before* the `register` because it's being passed as a parameter to `spawn` and that in turn to `register`.   I suspect the brackets after `math`  in the `spawn` call are not supposed to be there.

Comment: Exactly what @Alnitak said: Replace `start() -> register(myprocess, spawn(math, math(),  [])).` by `start() -> register(myprocess, spawn(math, math,  [])).` and it should work fine.

Comment: https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#registered-processes `'or undefined if the name is not registered'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parens on the `math()` parameter passed to `spawn`.

The second parameter to `spawn` is supposed to be the atom for the name of the process, but you're actually invoking the function and passing the result to spawn (all of which has to happen before `register` itself is called).